# npm: Upload a package from github which is not mine

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to use a package but it is not in npm. I'm thinking of uploading the package I need to npm, but I do not know if it's a good idea to upload a package that is not mine.
What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load it from Github. NPM supports this in the package.json file.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "expressjs/express",
    "mocha": "mochajs/mocha#4727d357ea",
    "module": "user/repo#feature\/branch"
  }
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls

Comment: Maybe this does not like the developer that created the package, perhaps only in general the owners upload their packages to npm if they wish. But if I usually upload something that is not yours, I guess it's ok. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the licensing of the package it could be a problem. You would want to check in with the author of the package before doing anything.

Comment: package.json says It has MIT license.